# "Installing" GD for PHP

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php

I'm new to server admin & Linux and have just got a VPS running CentOS 6.

Apache, MySQL and PHP all came installed (along with cPanel and WHM), however I'm now also trying to install the GD library.

I've run "yum install php-gd" and it installed ok. If I run it again I get "Package php-gd-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version".

However, when I do a phpinfo() or from the command line "php -m" there is no mention of GD. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Did you try to restart/reload apache before checking with phpinfo?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that I have restarted apache and the whole VPS

Comment: Thanks for the above help, but none of those solved the problem. Incase anyone else has the same issue, my solution is below....

Login to WHM
Go to "EasyApache (Apache Update)" under Software
Click "Start customizing based on profile"
Hit next until you get to step 5 then click "Exhaustive Options List" at the bottom
Check off GD under the PHP options
Save and Build

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart Apache for the new module to take effect:

```
# service httpd restart
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that I have restarted apache and the whole VPS.

Comment: Make sure that it is enabled by `extension=gd.so` in `/etc/php.d/gd.ini` or `/etc/php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

You have noticed that cPanel/WHM is also running on the VPS. Please take into account, that cPanel software compiles Apache/PHP and their modules from their own repos with custom flags and patches, therefore one should use their native `/scripts/easyapache` way of managing the LAMP bundle.

You can find more details on the official site [EasyApache Docs](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/WebHome)

Comment: This sounds like the issue.